# When do enemy armies get an extra turn?

Tags: romance-of-the-three-kingdoms-11

In the PC version of Romance of the Three Kingdoms XI, all enemy factions/armies get an entire extra turn at some point. This happens perhaps once per scenario/game. Enemy units can be observed to move and attack twice.

Why does this happen?

Can it be predicted?

Can it be avoided?

Comment: Can you claify?  The enemy side gets an entire extra turn (as in all their armies move), or are you asking of a particular unit gets an extra turn (or extra attack?).

Comment: I'll may dig up my copy of RoTKXI later to try to replicate.  I don't remember this happening but its been years since I played this game.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this.

Comment: Well, you have to play for hours, and it's not exactly announced to you. You're in a battle, planning your next move as the AI takes his turn(s), and suddenly they're moving again.

Comment: It may have to do with the number of action points (APs) you have remaining, or that you and the AI have relative to one another. That would make sense, wouldn't it?* But I see no mention of this behavior in the Help.


*If you end your turn with 0 points, then the AI takes a turn and has 100 points left, I can see the reasoning behind it. I have never gotten an extra turn, but sometimes my AP suddenly skyrockets.

Comment: I have played the PC version twice till the end and there no issue like that.

Comment: I just saw it again yesterday. I'm playing Ma Chao, and Cao Pi's armies froze in place while first Liu Bei and then I attacked. Nothing with a blue flag moved.

So it's pretty clear to me that this does in fact occur.

Answer (score 1):

The double move is just due to the ordering of turns.  If you take your turn before the enemy, then they take their turn the next month before you, it will seem like they just got a double turn.  But everyone still moves just one turn per month.

Comment: Hmm. That's possible. But why would that happen at all? And that would mean that _I_ would then get a double turn, which does not seem to happen.

There's definitely something "off" about the way the game calculates points, especially when I hold a council. But while I might not notice if I were handed a new turn's set of action points, I would certainly notice if I had a new list of moveable units when I thought my turn was over.

But it could still be that I don't see the enemies' lack of movement because I'm looking elsewhere or I walked away.

Comment: @Alveric I did manage to reproduce this last night and that's what it seemed like to me, the enemy had 2 turns between my turns.

Comment: Aha! Well, thanks for confirming this behavior. I do suspect it has to do with under- or over-using your APs. Possibly it's meant to compensate the AI.

Do you ever see miscalculated points? (i.e., a long string of numerals instead of the actual remainder) after a council?

Comment: @Alveric nope, I've never seen that.  Though I tend to keep my APs under 100

Answer (score 1):

AI does not get extra turn in ROTK XI, ever.  What you observed is an enemy unit movement followed by normal attack + another normal attack triggered by "Chain Attack" skill of the enemy officer.  Now, this double attack per turn does not trigger every time, but rather has about 50% chance to occur.

Also, some officers will assist other officers after they have already moved for that turn, which may seem like they are attacking twice, and even trice per turn.  Once again, both player and AI get to do stuff once per turn no matter what.

Comment: Thanks, but that is a different, individual event. As I said, ALL enemy factions/armies seem to get an ENTIRE extra turn in which they ALL move and attack. Or as restated, "the enemy side gets an entire extra turn (as in all their armies move)." See my last comment above for a likely explanation. It may have to do with conserved AI action points.

Note this is the same answer as below.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't get an extra turn, but there are officers like "Bao Sanniang" if I remember correctly, that have an skill called "chain attack".

With these officers you have the probability of "attacking" twice in a single turn.

Regards

Comment: Right, but I'm talking about entire armies.